# Do Windows environments in Parallels have virtualization enabled?

Tags: virtualization

I have a MacBook Pro. I need to run Windows with virtualization enabled. I need to be able to run Hyper-V and Docker images in my Windows environment. My question is, do Windows environments in Parallels have virtualization enabled? Can I run Hyper-V / Docker images within Windows within Parallels?

I intend to use Windows 10 Enterprise. In regards to Docker, I'm currently using Community Edition, but I'm open to using another version if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, do Windows environments in Parallels have
>   virtualization enabled?

If you are asking if the current version of `Parallels Desktop 13 for Mac`, supports nested virtualization then the answer to that question is, it does indeed.

> Parallels Desktop provides nested virtualization support (VT-X
>   technology) that allows you to run Hyper-V virtual machines inside
>   Windows 8, 10 and Windows Server 2012 virtual machines.

When you create the virtual machine you will have to enable `nested virtualization` in order for it to work.

[image]

Source: [Nested Hyper-V support in Parallels Desktop virtual machines](https://kb.parallels.com/en/116239)

The documentation for Parallels Desktop for Mac indicate, only the professional and Business editions support nested virtualization.

> - Parallels Desktop for Mac Business Edition
> - Parallels Desktop for Mac Pro Edition